# Bash: duplicate + rename folder

Tags: bash, shell, directory, rename

Suppose I have a folder named `my_folder_old` in `/path/to/folder`, how can I create a duplicate named `my_folder_new` in the same directory?

**EDIT**

Moreover if `my_folder_new` already exists, `my_folder_old` is created inside the first and not substituted. Why is this happening?

Comment: cp -rp /path/to/folder/my_folder_old /path/to/folder/my_folder_new check: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/copy-folder-linux-command-line/

Comment: The reason why is this happening because, my_folder_new already created. Doing same cp command it will see as new path, /path/to/folder/my_folder_new/. To workaround current situation, check if directory exists and copy like this: cp -frp /path/to/folder/my_folder_old/* /path/to/folder/my_folder_new/*

Comment: Ok, thanks. If you post your solution as an answer I can flag it as accepted:)

Comment: Is that really worth a downvote? Because the first link doesn't really address my question while the cp man is detailed but also very general.

Comment: it's not me who down-vote :) Just as example why someone down-voting link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Tutorial copy files, folder link: [link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/copy-folder-linux-command-line/)

Manual cp command : [Link](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html)

```
cp -frp /path/to/folder/my_folder_old -T /path/to/folder/my_folder_new

   -f, --force
          if an existing destination file cannot be opened, remove it
          and try again (this option is ignored when the -n option is
          also used)
   -p     same as --preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps
   -R, -r, --recursive
          copy directories recursively
   -T, --no-target-directory
          treat DEST as a normal file
```

*Though if my_folder_new already exists, my_folder_old is created inside the first and not substituted. Why is this happening?*

The reason why is this happening because, my_folder_new already created. Doing same cp command it will see as new path, /path/to/folder/my_folder_new/

Comment: maybe we could make a function in `.bashrc` called for example `dup /path/to/folder` to create `folder_copy_n` where `n` was the number of copy. the function would look into the `path/to/` to see if `folder_copy_<n-1>` already exists.

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with this same issue, was going crazy ahaha, I tried cp -frp but did not work, so, before of going to do cp just remove the existing folder using rm, see below more info about this:

[Remove Directory Linux](https://linuxize.com/post/remove-directory-linux/)

> If a directory or a file within the directory is write-protected, you will be prompted to confirm the deletion. To remove a directory without being prompted, use the -f option:

```
rm -rf dir1
```